# Setting EDITOR=nvim Changes tmux to Vi mode, but does not affect default terminal

Tags: zsh, tmux, zshrc

I'm currently using tmux version 3.3a on macOS Ventura. I have configured the `EDITOR` environment variable in my `.zprofile` to use nvim. Interestingly, this adjustment seems to change keybindings to vi mode in tmux, but it doesn't have the same effect on my default terminal.

When I execute zsh's `bindkey -e`, it switches back to Emacs mode. Can anyone explain why changing the `EDITOR` variable impacts tmux keybindings but not the default terminal's?

Comment: To set vi mode vor editing the command line, the command is `set -o vi`. The variable `EDITOR` specifies the default text editor for various programs, for instance `less` or `git`. It seems that `tmux` is also one of them.

Comment: As for `bindkey`, if you do in your shell a `type bindkey`, you will get as response _bindkey is a shell builtin_.